# How does KafkaUtils.createDirectStream() achieve exactly-once semantics?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Not sure if my understand to this question is correct:

Using `KafkaUtils.createStream()`, the program itself is a consumer that receives data passively. Since `Kafka` only maintains its own offset, `Kafka` does not know where the program consumes. 
So if `Kafka` failure occurs, it may resend data that had been sent to receiver and this leads to duplicate data.

While using `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream()`, the program itself directly consumes internal `Kafka` partitions, so it knows where it consumes, and no matter itself or `Kafka` fails, it can re-consume from the correct position.

I want to confirm if my understand is correct. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In the Structured Streaming documentation ... *The engine uses checkpointing and write ahead logs to record the offset range of the data being processed in each trigger. The streaming sinks are designed to be idempotent for handling reprocessing. Together, using replayable sources and idempotent sinks, Structured Streaming can ensure end-to-end exactly-once semantics under any failure*

Comment: @cricket_007 Why don't you answer the question (using the comment)?

Comment: @Jacek Question appears not to be asking about Structured Streaming? And AFAIK, consumption from Kafka is at-least-once. The above quote says for sinks specifically

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for your reply. I am new to spark and such document description is still confusing to me... Could you please show me an example?

Comment: Sorry, example of what? These are just words, there is no concrete example